# Нормализация пути к папке или файлу

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Нужно по именам бизнес-сущностей создавать папки и подпапки в них, чтобы названия были максимально близки к оригинальным.

При этом, надо учитывать ограничения операционной системы, что добавляет мороки - если на linux-macos ограничений фактически нет, то на windows их более чем полно.

Получился вот такой код, недопустимые символы заменяются на точку.

```
private static readonly string NormalizationPattern = string.Format(@"([{0}]*\.+$)|([{0}]+)", Regex.Escape(string.Concat(new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()), "?", "/", "*", "\"")));
private static readonly string[] DosReservedNames = { "CON", "PRN", "AUX", "NUL", "COM0", "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9", "LPT0", "LPT1", "LPT2", "LPT3", "LPT4", "LPT5", "LPT6", "LPT7", "LPT8", "LPT9" };

public static string NormalizePath(string name)
{
  if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix ||
      Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.MacOSX)
    return name;

  const string replacement = ".";
  var matchesCount = Regex.Matches(name, @":\\").Count;
  string correctName;
  if (matchesCount > 0)
  {
    var regex = new Regex(@":", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
    correctName = regex.Replace(name, replacement, regex.Matches(name).Count - matchesCount);
  }
  else
    correctName = name.Replace(":", replacement);

  var replace = Regex.Replace(correctName, NormalizationPattern, replacement);
  foreach (var reservedName in DosReservedNames)
  {
    var builder = new List<string>();
    foreach (var folder in replace.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
    {
      var changedName = folder;
      if (string.Equals(folder, reservedName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        changedName = replacement + reservedName;

      var value = reservedName + '.';
      if (folder.StartsWith(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        changedName = replacement + value + folder.Remove(0, value.Length);

      builder.Add(changedName);
    }

    replace = string.Join<string>(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), builder);
  }
  return replace.TrimEnd(' ', '.');
}
```

Корень папки обычно выбирается в системе и он уже существует. А дальше все уровни вложенности создаются через нормализацию. Поэтому например тримминг точек и пробелов сделан только в конце, а не на каждом уровне. Может и не стоит так делать и стоит триммить имя каждой папки.

На это всё написаны тесты, кейсы в целом выглядят вот так:

```
[Test, Sequential]
public void CheckNotAllowedNames([Values(
  "test"
  ,@"C:\somename\somename:name"
  ,@"usr\home\somename:name"
  ,@"start < > : "" / \ | ? * end"
  ,"\x15\x3D" // less than ASCII space
  ,"\x21\x3D" // HEX of !, valid
  ,"\x3F\x3D" // HEX of ?, not valid
  ,@"C:\somename\   trailing space   "
  ,@"C:\somename\...trailing period..."
  ,@"C:\somename\CON"
  ,@"C:\somename\CON.txt"
  ,@"CON"
  ,@"C:\somename\con.txt\context"
  ,@"home\NUL.liza"
  ,@"home\ NUL.liza"
  ,@"C:\somename\..." // Bad name get the root folder, bug =_=
  ,@"root\..\sub"
  ,@"root\..\"
  ,@".\..\some?folder"
  ,@"root\.." // relative path trimmed, bug =_=
)] string name, [Values(
  "test"
  ,@"C:\somename\somename.name"
  ,@"usr\home\somename.name"
  ,@"start . . . . . \ . . . end"
  ,".="
  ,"!="
  ,".="
  ,@"C:\somename\   trailing space"
  ,@"C:\somename\...trailing period"
  ,@"C:\somename\.CON"
  ,@"C:\somename\.CON.txt"
  ,@".CON"
  ,@"C:\somename\.CON.txt\context"
  ,@"home\.NUL.liza"
  ,@"home\ NUL.liza"
  ,@"C:\somename\"
  ,@"root\..\sub"
  ,@"root\..\"
  ,@".\..\some.folder"
  ,@"root\"
)] string expected)
{
  Assert.AreEqual(expected, NormalizePath(name));
}
```

---

Собственно, хочется во первых чтобы кто-то посмотрел и может нашел пропущенные мной ошибки.

А во вторых - может я изобретаю велосипед и где то есть готовая нормализация? Гуглил долго и упорно, но мог пропустить, велосипедов кругом полно.

---

UPD1: найдена проблема с относительными путями и её пока не представляю как решать, добавил тестов с текущим поведнием. Апи дотнета позволяет запросить создание папки `root\folder\.....` и возвращает при этом папку `root`. Справка на msdn говорит что точки через апи создать можно, но не стоит, чтобы не вызывать проблем. Как в итоге обрабатывать правильнее относительные пути - тот ещё вопрос.

Comment: я обычно меняю запрещенные символы на `_`. Точки действительно неудобный вариант. Готовых реализаций не видел.

Comment: @rdorn у меня тоже изначально подчеркивания были, пользователи жаловались что некрасиво, поменял на точки. Реальных кейсов, что эти точки превращаются в относительные пути - пока нет, но с подчеркиваниями действительно было бы проще. Пока в раздумьях, как лучше сделать.

Comment: В порядке бреда: найти символ точки, код которого не совпадает с кодом стандартной точки, в юникоде же работаем.

Comment: @rdorn я попробовал многоточие, в целом норм =) Но тут опять надо аккуратнее с относительными путями. А это меня уводит к другой теме - наверное надо отдельно валидировать путь из настроек и названия сущностей из бизнес логики.

Comment: Ну если корень задается настройками, а дальше по названиям сущностей, то да, стоит оба варианта валидировать независимо. А для относительных путей можно добавить проверку, что при автоматическом 
 и ручном преобразовании в абсолютный путь получаются эквивалентные пути. Это позволит выявить проблемы с точками, в теории. Можно еще в названиях сущностей запретить определенные символы, но это не всегда возможно по бизнес-логике.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, разделил явно логику по работе с корневой папкой, указанной в настройках и с папками бизнес объектов.

Папки настроек валидируются просто:

```
/// <summary>
/// Проверить путь к папке хранения указываемый в настройках.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">Путь к папке.</param>
/// <returns>True, если путь в порядке.</returns>
/// <remarks>Путь должен существовать или быть значением по умолчанию. Не должен заканчиваться относительными путями.</remarks>
public static bool ValidateSettingPath(string path)
{
  if (Equals(path, AppConfig.DownloadFolderName) || Equals(path, AppConfig.DownloadFolder))
    return true;

  if (path.TrimEnd(Path.PathSeparator, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.VolumeSeparatorChar).EndsWith("."))
    return false;

  return Directory.Exists(GetAbsoluteFolderPath(path));
}
```

А валидация папок от бизнес объектов фактически та, что в вопросе, но её получилось сильно упростить:

```
private static readonly string NormalizationPattern = string.Format(@"([{0}]*\.+$)|([{0}]+)", Regex.Escape(string.Concat(new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()), "?", "/", "*", "\"", ":", "\\")));
private static readonly string[] DosReservedNames = { "CON", "PRN", "AUX", "NUL", "COM0", "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9", "LPT0", "LPT1", "LPT2", "LPT3", "LPT4", "LPT5", "LPT6", "LPT7", "LPT8", "LPT9" };

/// <summary>
/// Очистка имени от недопустимых символов.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">Имя.</param>
/// <returns>Имя без недопустимых символов.</returns>
/// <remarks>В имени не должно быть разделителей, они будут восприниматься как часть имени.</remarks>
public static string RemoveInvalidCharsFromName(string name)
{
  if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix ||
      Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.MacOSX)
    return name;

  const string replacement = ".";

  var folder = Regex.Replace(name, NormalizationPattern, replacement);
  foreach (var reservedName in DosReservedNames)
  {
    var reservedNameWithDot = reservedName + '.';
    if (string.Equals(folder, reservedName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      folder = replacement + reservedName;
    else if (folder.StartsWith(reservedNameWithDot, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      folder = replacement + reservedNameWithDot + folder.Remove(0, reservedNameWithDot.Length);
  }

  // Если имя оказалось целиком из точек и\или пробелов - заменяем на константу.
  folder = folder.TrimEnd(' ', '.');
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folder))
    folder = "invalid name";

  return folder;
}
```

Текущая реализация требует вызова `RemoveInvalidCharsFromName` на каждый уровень вложенности. Т.е. если логика требует Folder1/Subfolder2/Subfolder3, то "нормализовать"
 надо каждую папку отдельно:

```
var path = Path.Combine(settingFolder, RemoveInvalidCharsFromName("Folder1"));
path = Path.Combine(path, RemoveInvalidCharsFromName("Subfolder2"));
path = Path.Combine(path, RemoveInvalidCharsFromName("Subfolder3"));
```